# Workflow engine

Tags: php, workflow

I am new to workflow engine how it work and how I can develop it; I have A LMS (Learning management Service) site. I need to have a dynamic workflow. Any suggestions on how I can develop it?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ezComponent' Workflow Engine](http://ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Workflow):

> The Workflow component provides a virtual machine that executes workflows represented through object graphs. These object graphs can be created programmatically through the software component's Workflow Definition API. Alternatively, a workflow definition can be loaded from an XML file. Object graph and XML file are two different representations of a workflow definition that uses a backend language built on the workflow patterns.

It has extensive documentation.

Or you can have a look at [Sebastian Bergmann's Diploma Thesis about Workflow Engines](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/publications/bergmann-WorkflowEngine-DiplomaThesis.pdf) that covers the nitty gritty academic details that went into said component.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be very easy to come up with one very quickly. probably you can try some open source/free engines, and see if that fits your requirement.

Have a look at this:
http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

Reading about them, selecting one of them to do initial trails will be a difficult choice. but that's how things are, atleast your work of coming up with one saved, now it's up to you to choose one of these appropriate to your requirement!